# Connect to remote server via telnet and update a file programmatically

Tags: java, telnet

I want to change the settings of a PROROUTE wireless cellular router (H685) from the web application.
The only way to change the settings, is to login to the router via telnet and change a file in the editor (i.e. vi) and reboot.

I want to do it programmatically from server side using JAVA,
I can connect to the router and send command, using TelnetClient

Here is the sample code to connect to the router via telnet and send command

```
public class Test
{
    private TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
    private InputStream in;
    private PrintStream out;
    private String prompt = "#";

    public Test(String server, String user, String password) {
        try {
            // Connect to the specified server
            telnet.connect(server, 23);
            // Get input and output stream references
            in = telnet.getInputStream();
            out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());
            // Log the user on
            readUntil("Login:");
            write(user);
            readUntil("Password:");
            write(password);
            // Advance to a prompt
            readUntil(prompt + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String readUntil(String pattern) {
        try {
            char lastChar = pattern.charAt(pattern.length() - 1);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            boolean found = false;
            char ch = (char) in.read();
            while (true) {
                System.out.print(ch);
                sb.append(ch);
                if (ch == lastChar) {
                    if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) {
                        return sb.toString();
                    }
                }
                ch = (char) in.read();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void write(String value) {
        try {
            out.println(value);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String sendCommand(String command) {
        try {
            write(command);
            return readUntil(prompt + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            telnet.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Test telnet = new Test("192.168.1.1", "username", "pwd");
            telnet.sendCommand("ls");
            telnet.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I have to update the file in the editor.

1. Send command to open the file in vi

$vi /flash/.disable_fun_list

function_dtu:

function_wifi:

function_gps:
.
.
.
.

function_wifi:on (this line needs to be changed)

and then send command to restart the router.

$reboot

Any idea, how this can be done.

Comment: Is it necessary to open the file in vi?Also, can't you create a temporary file, perform the modifications there, delete original file and replace it with the temporary file?

Comment: how about connecting with **ftp** instead and transferring files back and forth ?

Comment: once you are connected you can navigate to the file location, and do a `string replace` for the lines you wish to edit. check if `sed` for example is available ?!

Comment: @Plirkee **ftp** is not an option

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful That's what I though, can you please elaborate, how can it be done. I think, I can create 2 extra temp file with my settings and rename them depending on the wifi status?

Comment: @Yazan could you please share some code, how to navigate to a certain line and edit ? Thanks

Comment: i did not mean navigate to certain line, you can execute `vi -c 'command_to_replace' /file/path/fname` from the prompt, this way you can just replace the strings you wish and save the file by using `vi` command capabilities , check this http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/07/06/vi-edit-file-without-opening/

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking to do sounds a terrible idea.

I feel there is no need to open this file in `vi` editor. In such cases, people generally suggest to create a temporary file and replace it with the original.

Suggested approach :

1. Open the file which you want to modify using BufferedReader on top of FileReader.
2. Modify the string, if you've to replace the currently read line; if not, then simply proceed to step 3.
3. Now, once you've string ready(whether changed OR unchanged) to be written to a file, then create a temporary file, and write the read string(line) to this temporary file.
4. Once, you're done with all the line of the original file, then close the BufferedReader, and delete(or, better rename to something else) the original file. Rename the temp file to the original filename, and move this temp file to the location of the original file from where you've copied(and modified) the content!

Code should flow like :

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //Step 2 : do modification with the string read
   //Step 3 : write the final modified string inside a temp file.
   // Step 4 : close the br, and rename/delete the old file; rename the temp file to this original file.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `vi` from command line without actually opening the `vi` as an app

you can pass args to `vi` to do a string replace for what you need
and you can pass args to save the file, plus the file path of course.

so you might end up executing this command via telnet connection

```
vi -c "%s/function_wifi:on/function_wifi:off/g|wq" /path/to/config/file
```

this will replace the string `function_wifi:on` with `function_wifi:off` and save the file.

simply then send a `reboot` command.

for more check [this link](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/07/06/vi-edit-file-without-opening/)

Answer (score 0):

change above program to

```
private String prompt = ">";
```

instead of

```
private String prompt = "#";
```